# why do objects from a stream get mangled when inserted into mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript

I have messages I get from a stream that I am trying to insert into mongo. But the messages/objects get mangled when inserted. The code looks like this:

```
getFeed()
  .then((feed: SomeFeed) => {
    feed.on('data', (message: any) => {
      tickerCollection.insert(message, (error: MongoError, result: InsertOneWriteOpResult) => {
        if (error) {
          logger.log('error', error.message);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

If I insert the message like this, the data gets all mangled and looks like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5a937efe7a7d6b5917938a62"),
"type" : "mytype",
"time" : ISODate("2018-02-26T03:29:02.346Z"),
"altitude" : {
    "s" : 1,
    "e" : 3,
    "c" : [
        9690,
        1000000000000
    ],
    "isBigNumber" : true
},
"minAltitude" : {
    "s" : 1,
    "e" : 3,
    "c" : [
        9689,
        99000000000000
    ],
    "isBigNumber" : true
},
```

If I use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` together, the data inserts correctly:

```
getFeed()
  .then((feed: SomeFeed) => {
    feed.on('data', (message: any) => {
      let m = JSON.stringify(message);
      let o = JSON.parse(m);

      tickerCollection.insert(o, (error: MongoError, result: InsertOneWriteOpResult) => {
        if (error) {
          logger.log('error', error.message);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

And here the data is not mangled:

```
  "_id" : ObjectId("5a937f5bb6cced592803c446"),
  "type" : "mytype",
  "time" : "2018-02-26T03:30:34.854Z",
  "altitude" : "9690",
  "minAltitude" : "9689",
```

What am I missing?

Thanks much!

**Update**

Sample of raw object when output to console without `JSON.stringify()`. In the stream it comes in as type `any`. (some names have been changed to protect the innocent ;-) )

```
type=mytype, time=Tue Feb 27 2018 17:38:51 GMT+0700 (+07), 
productId=quencher, sequence=5253165159, s=1, e=4, c=[10664], s=1, e=4, 
c=[10663, 99000000000000], s=1, e=4, c=[10664], socks_id=38224576, s=1, 
e=-2, c=[3120000000000], sourceSequence=5253165159, type=mytype, 
sequence=5253165159, product_id=quencher, altitude=10664.00000000, 
minAltitude=9598.31000000
```

Comment: can you give a sample object of the stream that you receive?

Comment: updated in the question. thanks!